# Logic. Express the proposition in symbols

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Assume we are dealing only with integers.

Using only numerals, variables, logical symbols and the mathematical symbols, I need express the following proposition:

> $$100 \text{ is a multiple of } 5 $$

I've tried it, and, in my own words I came up with:

> If n is a multiple of 100 then 100 is multiple of 5.

Trying to see if this is right.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**"$100$ is a multiple of $5$"**  by definition:

$$\exists\, x\in \mathbb Z \;( \,5x = 100\,)$$

And we can verify that statement is true by showing the existence of such an integer x:

$$5x= 100 \iff x = \frac{100}{5} = 20, $$ noting that the one and only integer satisfying $5x = 100$ is $x=20$.

---

Note that there is another way with which to express **"$100$ is a multiple of $5$"** $\iff$  "$5$ **is a divisor** of $100$."  The notation used to express "$5$ **divides** $100$" is given by $$5\mid 100$$  And the logical definition given above expresses as much.

Comment: Thank you I understand right now. I also did it another way. If 100 is a multiple of n, then n is a multiple of 5. 100/20=5,  20/5=4.

Comment: Note that the uniqueness of $x$ ($\exists!$) is quite redundant and is rarely included in the definition of divisibility.

Comment: About the very first comment below my answer: In this case we have the proposition: 100 is a multiple of n ($n=5$) as given, and in this case, it also is trivially true that $n = 5$ is a multiple of 5.   But suppose we are told that $6$ is a multiple of $n=3$.  That is true because $6 = 2(3),$ but $3$ is not a multiple of $2$.  So I think you noticed a relation in this particular case, but the question concerns only how to symbolize the statement that $100$ is a multiple of $5$.

Answer (score 0):

We have,

n = 100k

= 5(20k)

So 100 is a multiple of 5.

Comment: Your right. But how does this expression be written in symbols. I'm confused

Comment: You are writing in your question symbols are allowed. So we can use.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Mine pleasure :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need it in logic:

$\exists x : 100 = 5 * x$